# Android: Register a SensorEventListener with a Handler?

Tags: android, multithreading, listeners, handlers

I'm new to Android and I'm trying to write an app that will send sensor data from a phone over the network to a PC.

I know I shouldn't do 'expensive' operations on the UI thread.  Android allows you to register  a SensorEventListener with a Handler.

```
public boolean registerListener (SensorEventListener listener, Sensor sensor, int rate, Handler handler)
```

Here's the link to the same [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/SensorManager.html#registerListener%28android.hardware.SensorEventListener,%20android.hardware.Sensor,%20int,%20android.os.Handler%29).

Would anybody be able to explain what the purpose of the Handler is?  Should I create a Handler that implements a SensorEventListener? That seems wrong to me, because then I would be passing the same object for two of the arguments (listener & handler).

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can start the Handler from the UI thread (it will be called once the SensorEvent is triggered), and in the handler create a new Thread that sends the sensor data over the network.